# what does the -@ mean when zipping a file in unix?

Tags: zip

I found this command online, but not sure what the `-@` means.

```
find . -type f -mtime -29 -mtime +21 | zip -@ 061110_061201.zip
```

Comment: thanks all, i am using MobaXterm and for some reason it doesn't return anything when i do a "man zip".

Comment: If you don't have the `zip` utility installed, then `man zip` will not work as the manual pages will not be installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you run `man zip` you can read:

```
-@ file lists.   If  a file list is specified as -@, zip
       takes the list of input files from standard input instead of  from  the
       command line.
```

You can refer to this [question on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/46372/115216) to better understand the difference between standard input and command line argument.

Comment: We used 3 different manuals it seems? funny.

Comment: so what exactly does that mean?  why would i want to use standard input instead of command line?

Comment: You can find a good explanation on the [difference between standard input and command line  arguments here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46372/whats-the-difference-between-stdin-and-arguments-passed-to-command). :)

Comment: @clayton33 then you can (for example) zip only files a) containing a word (`grep -l 'some-word' . -R | zip -@ ....`) b) owned by a particular user: `find . -type f -user someuser | zip -@ ...`) c) zip only duplicate files (`fdupes . | zip -@ ...`) ... Possibilities are infinite.

Comment: @Rinzwind that is why you should check http://manpages.ubuntu.com first.

Answer (score 4):

The manual has this option described as  (see `man zip` from command line or an [online version](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip))

```
 -@     Take the list of input files from standard input.  
        Only  one  filename per line.
```

So to explain your command. This will have an undetermined amount of results:

```
 find . -type f -mtime -29 -mtime +21
```

and the result of this is accepted by the 2nd part of the command but only 1 result at once but still processed to the same zip file.

```
zip -@ 061110_061201.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

according to `man zip`

```
-@ file lists.   If  a file list is specified as -@ [Not on MacOS], zip
   takes the list of input files from standard input instead of  from  the
   command line.  For example,

          zip -@ foo
```